# Translating a .NET DLL using Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I have written a networking library using C# and .NET. .NET/Mono developers can use the library to develop multiplayer applications.
I want to make the library available on the Android platform so that native Android developers can use the library. Is Monodroid (Mono for Android) capable of performing this translation and what is the best way to proceed?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you are looking to build a DLL using Mono for Android that you give to Java developers to use? That's not currently possible since Mono for Android isn't simply translating from C# to Java. Mono for Android apps include the Mono runtime, and .NET code is run against that. It generates callable wrappers so that Mono and Dalvik (the Java virtual machine in Android) can talk to each other, but without the Mono runtime the DLL wouldn't be very useful.

If the developer is using Mono for Android to build the application, then they can use your DLL in the app.

Comment: Why can't mono for android wrap the mono runtime with the .Net DLL (just like it does for other .NET apps). This way, the library should be usable by native Android developers (as it has the mono runtime). In theory, I don't see much difference between a .NET application and a .NET DLL (they are both .NET solutions/projects). If Mono for Android can translate .NET projects to run directly on Android then it should be able to handle a .NET project that is built as a library.

Comment: The runtime is what knows how to interpret and run your DLLs, so they operate at much different levels. I suggest reading through the docs on Mono for Android's architecture, which explain how everything is set up: http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture

Comment: I had a read of the architecture but still a bit confused as it clearly states that the Mono for Android stack includes the mono runtime. What you are suggesting is that the translated library will not have mono runtime included hence it cannot be used by native Android developers. Is that correct?

Comment: The Mono runtime is included as part of Mono for Android applications, not class libraries. There is no build step in which C# code is translated into Java code. The .NET code in the application (including class libraries) is run against the Mono runtime, so the library wouldn't be useful to someone building their app in Java since that runtime would not be there to interpret the code.